# retrieve database data with application server?

Tags: web-application, webserver, databases, appsec

retrieve database data with application server?

Comment: This question is rather vague. It's definitely possible, but it depends on a lot of factors. Is this a homework question, by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, yes. In many typical configurations, where servers have not had extensive security hardening, it would be possible.

Factors that might permit this:

- The application server would naturally require a network path to the database server, therefore any firewall would be configured to allow connections.
- The application server is likely, in a typical configuration, to be in possession of credentials for the database. These will often be stored inside the application's source code, or in a configuration file. (For example, the web.config file in ASP.NET applications.)

Therefore, the attacker could retrieve the credentials, and then use a database client on  the application server to query the database.

Some factors that might guard against this:

- Strict file permissions on the file containing the database credentials. The user account you have compromised (that you can run commands as) may not have sufficient privileges.
- Similarly, the database credentials themselves might be encrypted, with strict file permissions on the encryption key (or an encryption key protected by a [Hardware Security Module - HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)).
- Data within the database might be encrypted, with similar protection for the key as above.
- No credentials are stored, and authentication to the database is achieved through the application service's account credentials (e.g. via Kerberos to MSSQL). This would require a user with the correct database privileges to be compromised.

Most, if not all, of the above mechanisms could be defeated if the attacker had *administrative* control of the application server.

Comment: While you are correct that some applications store credentials in their source code, it's worth noting that it's almost always a bad idea. In on-prem products, all customers get the same creds - which means the creds are no longer secret. In a hosted product, you should have separation of duties between dev/qa and the prod support team. With hard coded creda, that separation is severely weakened.